# Android: Adding Lock Pattern to an activity

Tags: android, design-patterns

I'm developing an alarm application in which the alarm is set and then it is received by the Broadcast Receiver after that it will redirect to an activity.
I want to add a pattern lock at this activity. Once the correct combination of pattern is entered the phone will stop ringing.

**How do i add this pattern lock in the activity.**
Tried to implement the android-lockpattern library but doesn't know how to use it.

Comment: Yes i do, see i am receiving the broadcast receiver and passing the intent to an activity. The activity is launching after receiving the broadcast. This works fine.
My query is that i want pattern lock on that activity.

Comment: What i mean is , do you have a code for pattern lock to fix or you are asking for a code?

Comment: Sir i'm asking for code.

Comment: Go through this google demo project for pattern lock https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/

Comment: found this example. 
https://github.com/lucasandre/intelligent-lock-pattern

Thanks for the help sir.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this pattern lock activity in front of your activity which starts after alarm is rung.
then if pattern matches then Do whatever you want to Do

refer to this project for pattern lock.

https://github.com/Joisar/LockScreenApp

Comment: Its python code for cracking the android pattern lock. But i want to use the pattern lock in my activity.

Comment: @kamalvaid Its not pattern lock what he has asked for. Its simple drag and drop lock.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I caught the library which the link of demo app direct us. The library avaliable at site have problems. But the library found in link demo app link it's working. Using this library it's possible implement the guidelines site and compile without problems. See the options menu

> Export source code

at the demo app to get the library.